# How to prove that Radial Basis Function can be derived by mapping function?

Tags: self-study, gaussian-process, kernel-trick, radial-basis

How to prove the radial basis function $k(u,v) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \phi_t(u)\phi_t(v)dt $ can be integrated out by mapping function? $$\phi_{t}(u) = \frac{1}{(2\pi\Sigma)^{d/2}} \exp\left\{-\frac{\|u - t\|^2}{2\Sigma}\right\}$$
In other words, the integration will produce the radial basis function $$k(u,v) = \alpha \exp\left\{-\frac{\|u - v\|^2}{\beta}\right\}$$

Hope the problem is clear, it's my first time posting a question here.

Comment: (+1) Because this is a homework/self-study question, you should add the `self-study` tag to your question.

Comment: Hints: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat%C3%A9rn_covariance_function and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function#Types